# How to send Parse query into another ViewController

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm trying to send over a query salesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:objects] into EditData, i can't for the life of me figure it out. i'm trying to fill a picker view..i get the query executed with [parseConnection parseProduct] but can't get the array over to EditData.m

ParseConnection.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "Constants.h"
//#import "EditData.h"

@protocol ParseConnectionDelegate <NSObject>

@end

@interface ParseConnection : NSObject //<PFSubclassing>
{
  NSMutableArray *salesArray, *callbackArray, *contractorArray, *rateArray, *zipArray, *jobArray;    
}

- (void)parseSalesman;

@property (strong, nonatomic) id<ParseConnectionDelegate> delegate; //added

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *salesName;
```

ParseConnection.m

```
    #import "ParseConnection.h"

    @interface ParseConnection ()
    {
      //  NSMutableArray *salesArray, *callbackArray, *contractorArray, *rateArray, *zipArray, *jobArray;
    }
    @end

    @implementation ParseConnection

    #pragma mark - EditData PickerView
    - (void)parseSalesman {
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Salesman"];
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCACHEPOLICY;
        [query selectKeys:@[@"SalesNo"]];
        [query selectKeys:@[@"Salesman"]];
        [query orderByDescending:@"SalesNo"];
        [query whereKey:@"Active" containsString:@"Active"];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            salesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:objects];
             // NSLog(@"adStr is %@",salesArray);
        }];
    }
```

EditData.m

```
#import "EditData.h"

@interface EditData ()
{
    NSMutableArray *salesArray, *callbackArray, *contractorArray, *rateArray;
}
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIStepper *defaultStepper;
@end

@implementation EditData
@synthesize custNo, leadNo, active, date, first, last, company, address, city, state, zip, phone, aptDate, email, amount, spouse, callback, saleNo, jobNo, adNo, photo, comment, rate, start, complete;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;  //fix
    self.listTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.listTableView.delegate = self;
    self.listTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.listTableView.estimatedRowHeight = ROW_HEIGHT;
    self.listTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 0, 0);
 // self.listTableView.tableHeaderView = view; //makes header move with tablecell


     ParseConnection *parseConnection = [[ParseConnection alloc]init];
    [parseConnection parseProduct];
      NSLog(@"adStr is %@",self.adName.text);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a `salesArray` inside `ParseConnection`, pass in the one you have inside `EditData`.  Then, in your completion block, add objects to it rather than initializing it.

Don't forget to init `salesArray` in `EditData` before passing it as a parameter to the `parse...` method.

Comment: can you give an example...new at this